# Another Visual Studio 2015 Debugging Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I have searched all over the web, read and tried every solution I could find and none of them have solved my issue.

I have a web site on Azure. It is an App Service.

I am developing with the latest patched Visual Studio 2015.

I am able to right click in server explorer on my web app and attach to debugger.

None of the break points activate. They all have the error that symbols have not been loaded.

I made sure to build the site in debug.

I verified that the PDB files are on the server (using service explorer and looking at actual files).

I verified that the PDB files match what I have by date and time.

I tried to manually attach the debugger using the menu.

I put in mysite.azurewebsites.net:4020 as the server and am asked to log in. I use my credentials and they don't work.

I tried created a username and password on the azure portal credentials page for FTP. I tried using those and it still won't let me log in.

I am able to deploy using Web Deploy in the publish wizard.

I have no idea how to fix this. I must be able to debug my site.

I have 2 slots and tried debugging either of those and that doesn't work.

I tried debugging the main (production slot) and get the same results.

Help???

Comment: Did you debug your app in debug mode(not release mode), local or remote?  Did you enable the "Microsoft symbols servers" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols? Or If you view the Debug Modules window in debugging time, whether all symbols were loaded there? Which kind of process did you attach to, the dnx.exe or w3wp?

Comment: I turned on the symbols servers. That did not change anything. When I open the Debug Modules window it is empty. The only way I have been able to attach at all is through the Server Explorer by opening my azure account and finding the slot I want to debug and right licking to attach to it. I have no idea what process it is attaching to because it never gives me a chance to specify it. When I try to use Cloud Explorer or the manual Attach to Process by browsing to my server I get an authentication error even though I use the correct user name and password.